# QSortFilterProxyModel breaks columnWidths

Tags: qt, qtableview, qheaderview

What is the standard practice in keeping column widths saved within a QTableView which is having certain columns hidden/removed via a QSortFilterProxyModel (in arbitrary order)?  Note that I'm talking about having them hidden and unhidden within a single instance.

I've tried a number of ways (all ugly) to get it going.  Surely I'm doing something wrong.

I've looked at QHeaderView::saveState() and QHeaderView::restoreState(), but unless I'm missing something, this is really only good for saving from shutdown to start.  Once columns are hidden and unhidden in a different order, this breaks.

The QSortFilterProxyModel works fine using filterAcceptsColumn().  The caveat is when filterAcceptsColumn() returns true on a column that previously returned false.  I run invalidateFilter() and it's painted in the QTableView.  However, the QTableView is using some default value (100 it seems) for the column width instead of what the width was before the QSortFilterProxyModel hid the column.

Ideas?

Comment: For such control, is it smarter to just use QHeaderView::setSectionHidden() and do away with a QSortFilterProxy all together?

The other solution I started but thought was a little too cumbersome is to keep some type of container of "real indexes" verses what QHeaderView thinks are indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `setSectionHidden()` instead.

In general, you should try to keep code related to the view (like showing/hiding columns at runtime) out of the model. In our applications we have subclasses of `QTableView` and `QHeaderView` which allow the user to show/hide columns using a context menu; the column widths (and also positions) are not touched when showing/hiding them.

`filterAcceptsColumn` could maybe be used for disabling columns like Primary Keys, Foreign Keys etc completely.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  That helps.

From what I have noticed though, there is a caveat with using setSectionHidden() as opposed to blocking it in the QSortFilterProxModel. And that is, paint() will still paint the hidden cells... at least when the filter is invalidated.

[OOPS EDIT:]
However, I see what you mean.  QSortFilterProxy model should probably be used less for arbitrary filtering, and more for some type of preset filtering.  Seems to make sense.

Anywho, I think I will continue on in this mode, as I've spent *WAY* too much time on this. :)